# Получение хеш-значения пароля с помощью crypt(3)

Tags: linux, c, syscall

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE                                                                                        
                                                                     
int main(int argc, char **argv){ /*argv[1] -- key; argv[2] -- salt*/ 
  char* c=crypt(argv[1], argv[2]);                                   
  write(1, c, sizeof(c));                                            
  return 0;                                                          
}
```

В man-е сказано, что если нужно получить строку $6$salt$encryped (именно в таком виде она в файле /etc/shadow) необходимо передать ф-ии crypt() два аргумента: key и $6$salt$. При вызове программы ./a.out qwerty '$6$salt$'
она просто возвращает второй аргумент.

Comment: Не к вопросу, так, чисто на всякий случай - вы понимаете, что `sizeof(c)` - это размер указателя, т.е. 4 байта в 32-разрядном приложении и 8 - в 64-разрядном?

Comment: В мане  много чего сказано, в том числе какого размера строки в ответе

Comment: @Alexey Ten , в этой программке, как вы могли заметить, соль задается админом, вручную (да, в ущерб безопасности). Она может быть меньше 16 символов.

Comment: @Harry, да мне стыдно. И спасибо, это было как раз к вопросу.

Comment: The "encrypted" part of the password string is the actual
       computed password.  The size of this string is fixed: [···] SHA-512 | 86 characters

Comment: 86 символов -- это длина части encrypted, там еще 3 доллара, id алгоритма и еще кое-что. В этом вся соль.

Comment: В man не совсем удачно выразились, скажем. Можно было: The size of this part is fixed